# how to bind sharepoint2010 list to aspnet repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

In sharepoint2010, I have to bind a list with three columns(id, Name, cod) to reapeter control. 
I use following code but the result is a empty page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UploadC" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <table width="100%" class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">        
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3 class="ms-standardheader" 
                    style="font-size:large; color: #FF0000; text-align: center;" align="center">
                    Search</h3>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="ResultSet" runat="server" >
                      <ItemTemplate>
                      -Repeater-
                      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Lid" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LUSer" Value='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
                      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LCod" Value='<%# Eval("cod") %>' />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:Repeater>     
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

while the code-behind is:

```
List<DocumentModel> mylist = new List<DocumentModel>();
SPListItemCollection items = oDocumentset.GetItems(query);
   if (items.Count != 0)
   {
       foreach (SPListItem i in items)
       {
           DocumentModel doc = new DocumentModel();
           doc.id = i["id"].ToString();
           doc.name = i["Name"].ToString();
           doc.cod = i["Cod"].ToString();
           mylist.Add(doc);
       }
   }
       this.ResultSet.Visible = true;
       ResultSet.DataSource = mylist;
       ResultSet.DataBind();
```

thanks.

Comment: did you check that mylist is not empty ? if it has items, what event you are binding this repeater in ? because maybe the Update Panel triggers not set correctly

Comment: mylist isn't empty and the repeater is in the pageload()

Comment: what is this line in the html -Repeater- ??

Comment: nothing just i show it in the page like text

Comment: The boundfields are properties or not ?

Comment: Yes, they are properties

Comment: because there is no error its hard to catch, we need to make small experiment, outside the update panel add a gridview just bind it with same code and use even dynamic generated columns and see if any error will come or it will bind correctly